# Windows Open Dialog Box hangs forever with Address Sanitizer enabled

Tags: c++, winapi, com, address-sanitizer

When Address Sanitizer is enabled, the Open Dialog Box cannot be shown. It hangs forever.
Thank you.

It hangs when running             `hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog* pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
            IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine (it's not really doing anything). Maybe you are running it in debug mode, and Visual Studio takes a long time to load the debug crap (check the left-hand corner in Visual Studio IDE). By the way, you should call `CoUninitialize` even if `CoInitializeEx` failed, it's different than other related functions.

Comment: Nothing is being loaded. It just hangs.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani "*By the way, you should call `CoUninitialize` even if `CoInitializeEx` failed*" - not true. It must be called only if `CoInitialize/Ex()` is *successful*, not *failed*. The documentation even says so. The only 2 return values that indicate success, and thus require `CoUninitialize()`, are `S_OK` and `S_FALSE`. Anything else is a failure, so do not call `CoUninitialize()` for that call to `CoInitialize/Ex()`.

Comment: It seems an issue, I suggest you could post the issue to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8) for better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The fix is available in current [VS 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.1#issues-addressed-in-this-release-of-1716) and [VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.13)

---

Partial workaround for older VS:

To make this occur less often, add `SetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), 1);` at the beginning of your program. This seem to fix completely Open Dialog case, but doesn't fix more complex occurrences. (Be sure not to keep this workaround for normal program runs, as it effectively disables running on multiple CPU cores)